# Merging separate Postgres INSERT and SELECT statements into one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to merge Insert statement like this

```
INSERT into testing_sql(name, age) values ('Jim', '28');
```

and Select all statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM testing_sql ;
```

into one SQL statement ?

Comment: Is `Jim` ad `28 part of the select result?

Comment: `INSERT into testing_sql(name, age) values ('Jim', '28') returning *;` It is documented here [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Thanks but this will return just one row. What I am asking for is return all records after a single insert if that makes it clear.